# decrypt php soap response

Tags: java, php, encryption, soap

Im currently trying to build a php page that sends XML based data to a SOAP service at a provider which then returns with an encrypted response.

I need help to figure out how to decrypt the response.

I have changed the names a bit so that the code is anonymous.

Here is all the code i've been "playing" with:

```
// Turn on error reporting

error_reporting(-1);

// Triple linebreak function
function tlb() {
echo "<br /><br /><br />";
}


//  Test XML

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
SOME XML';


// SOAP Config
$soapConfig = array(
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'trace' => true,
    'exceptions' => true,
    'encoding' => "ISO-8859-1",
    //'use' => SOAP_LITERAL,
    'verify_peer' => true,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create([
        'ssl' => [
            'local_cert' => $wsdlcertpem,
            'passphrase' => $wsdlpasspem
        ]
    ])
);


// SOAP Connection

$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdlurl, $soapConfig);


// SOAP Function

try {
    $soapClient->function($xml);
}
catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring: {$fault->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);
}


// Load into variables

$LastRequestHeaders = $soapClient->__getLastRequestHeaders();
$LastRequest = $soapClient->__getLastRequest();
$LastResponseHeaders = $soapClient->__getLastResponseHeaders();
$LastResponse = $soapClient->__getLastResponse();
$b64LastResponse = base64_decode($LastResponse);

// Echo output

echo "SOAP XML:<pre>". htmlentities($xml) ."</pre>";
tlb();
echo "SOAP REQUESTHEADERS: <pre>$LastRequestHeaders</pre";
tlb();
echo "SOAP REQUEST: <pre>$LastRequest</pre>";
tlb();
echo "SOAP RESPONSEHEADERS:<pre>$LastResponseHeaders</pre>";
tlb();
echo "SOAP RESPONSE:<pre>$LastResponse</pre>";
tlb();
echo "SOAP RESPONSE Base64Decoded: <pre>$b64LastResponse</pre>";
tlb();


// Check signature on data

$key = openssl_pkey_get_public('$wsdlcertpem');

echo "$key";

$ok = "";
$signature = "";
$ok = openssl_verify($LastResponse, $signature, $key, sha1WithRSAEncryption);
echo "Check: <br/>";
if ($ok == 1) {
    echo "Signature OK";
} elseif ($ok == 0) {
    echo "Signature BAD";
} else {
    echo "Error checking signature";
}
echo "<br/>".$ok."";


tlb();
tlb();
// Attempt to decrypt 

if (!$publicKey = openssl_pkey_get_public($wsdlcerttestpem))
{
    echo "Public Key failed: $publicKey";
    die;
}
$a_key = openssl_pkey_get_details($publicKey);

// Decrypt the data in the small chunks
$chunkSize = ceil($a_key['bits'] / 8);
$output = '';
echo "ChunkSize: $chunkSize";
$encrypted = $b64LastResponse;


$decrypt_block_size = 256;
$decrypted = "";
$data = str_split($b64LastResponse, $decrypt_block_size);
foreach ($data as $chunk)
{
    $partial = "";
    $decryptionok = "";
    $decryptionok = openssl_public_decrypt($chunk, $partial, $publicKey);
    if($decryptionOK === false){return false;}//here also processed errors in decryption. If too big this will be false
    $decrypted .= $partial;
}

echo "Decrypteddata: $decrypted <br/>";

while ($encrypted)
{
    $chunk = substr($encrypted, 0, $chunkSize);
    $encrypted = substr($encrypted, $chunkSize);
    $decrypted = '';
    if (!openssl_public_decrypt($chunk, $decrypted, $publicKey))
    {
        echo "Failed to decrypt data";
        //die;
    }
    $output .= $decrypted;
}
openssl_free_key($publicKey);
echo "Decrypted data: $output";
// Uncompress the unencrypted data.
//$output = gzuncompress($output);

echo '<br /><br /> Unencrypted Data: ' . $output;




?>
```

Headers indicate that the SOAP itself works just fine.

The SOAP response comes up like this:

> ```
> MIIIZgYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIIVzCCCFMCAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMIIBRAYJKoZI
> hvcNAQcBoIIBNQSCATE8P3htbCB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjAiIGVuY29kaW5nPSJJU08t
> ODg1OS0xIj8+CjxyZXBseT48ZXJyb3I+PGludmFsaWQtZGF0YT48ZXJyb3ItY29k
> ZT5DVUkwNTE8L2Vycm9yLWNvZGU+PGVycm9yLXRleHQ+ZmVqbCB2ZWQgWE1MIGlu
> ZGdhbmc8L2Vycm9yLXRleHQ+PGVycm9yLXRleHQtZXh0ZW5kZWQ+b3JnLnhtbC5z
> YXguU0FYRXhjZXB0aW9uOiBFeGVjcHRpb24gZHVyaW5nIHBhcnNlOiBDb250ZW50
> IGlzIG5vdCBhbGxvd2VkIGluIHByb2xvZy48L2Vycm9yLXRleHQtZXh0ZW5kZWQ+
> PC9pbnZhbGlkLWRhdGE+PC9lcnJvcj48L3JlcGx5PqCCBSowggUmMIIEDqADAgEC
> AgMJZYMwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwPDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFzAVBgNVBAoTDkdl
> b1RydXN0LCBJbmMuMRQwEgYDVQQDEwtSYXBpZFNTTCBDQTAeFw0xMjExMjcxMjE2
> MDJaFw0xNjExMjgxMzM5MTVaMIG/MSkwJwYDVQQFEyB4dDZReWVJRkJNSWNNSjVK
> bjY0cEZZa25UeFljaFF2dTETMBEGA1UECxMKR1Q1NDU2NDM2NzExMC8GA1UECxMo
> U2VlIHd3dy5yYXBpZHNzbC5jb20vcmVzb3VyY2VzL2NwcyAoYykxMjEvMC0GA1UE
> CxMmRG9tYWluIENvbnRyb2wgVmFsaWRhdGVkIC0gUmFwaWRTU0woUikxGTAXBgNV
> BAMTEGthcmVuZGVtby50ZGMuZGswggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEK
> AoIBAQC7/9Yf14WIY8xC3ZtDTWSm40L2deF9reAnHL3aYEwtMmoN/k1sYaYOg2Pf
> TUOaUD/f9cBLagjyovFTun6S8maleCm6nuubuZePostWsJm9NjgL3ne1+0bQg9Iu
> aUL/99ThjCPj1Kw9sCcGIEu3X1ryMNIvUj6IVDPw6EIq/oonwYzVjyOsdyOO6bZ1
> vJvtwKDlW3JIePF+HyN9aOKQMfE3e2TY6isFrLySqJw29niz/d6DM3H3H64AWZAa
> pvaPNKehHV0s5ZnvuoZK9qRK1mh4hiq9SIeS1nCfW4qD8cOn14cNdcaEQntrzUs1
> dnLJ4CaITaKXZS1ZpYfqAnyFoWHzAgMBAAGjggGrMIIBpzAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBRr
> aT1qGEJK3Y8CZTn9NSSGeJEWMDAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCBaAwHQYDVR0lBBYwFAYI
> KwYBBQUHAwEGCCsGAQUFBwMCMBsGA1UdEQQUMBKCEGthcmVuZGVtby50ZGMuZGsw
> QwYDVR0fBDwwOjA4oDagNIYyaHR0cDovL3JhcGlkc3NsLWNybC5nZW90cnVzdC5j
> b20vY3Jscy9yYXBpZHNzbC5jcmwwHQYDVR0OBBYEFK3tOGh0xHCWZ8VD4cqGx03T
> j3wdMAwGA1UdEwEB/wQCMAAweAYIKwYBBQUHAQEEbDBqMC0GCCsGAQUFBzABhiFo
> dHRwOi8vcmFwaWRzc2wtb2NzcC5nZW90cnVzdC5jb20wOQYIKwYBBQUHMAKGLWh0
> dHA6Ly9yYXBpZHNzbC1haWEuZ2VvdHJ1c3QuY29tL3JhcGlkc3NsLmNydDBMBgNV
> HSAERTBDMEEGCmCGSAGG+EUBBzYwMzAxBggrBgEFBQcCARYlaHR0cDovL3d3dy5n
> ZW90cnVzdC5jb20vcmVzb3VyY2VzL2NwczANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOCAQEAR8IY
> eoLohTPFZd2ZoCAKqzreoiu2j3yCXeMDFHyIHX9bh5HmuSCmf25xsZeCcbXRH2a0
> q+ym0X2BCqcJUMLuFKR83O/IN8z6iATQ6ZjccRg26KA1CB6NTVOi7NM13cqo9ucF
> KeDec2sFI9lrrphtWZwUbERprnjW6V0AorgdOukxCiCEPelmQogolIlDGHL6k83E
> QaLhznItOYwEgTdnJ6Okb4jP6pjxJKD8medi52ICjeeUmeHJXuKhI0wUFP+wcelF
> CpMco1Qs+mdVZ1FCNbw83KUwh5XwM4tKzgn5ipKomsPx4h6eQYpDoe4ulivH+xYN
> YNcLs+HijvkbmmV+3TGCAckwggHFAgEBMEMwPDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFzAVBgNV
> BAoTDkdlb1RydXN0LCBJbmMuMRQwEgYDVQQDEwtSYXBpZFNTTCBDQQIDCWWDMAkG
> BSsOAwIaBQCgXTAYBgkqhkiG9w0BCQMxCwYJKoZIhvcNAQcBMBwGCSqGSIb3DQEJ
> BTEPFw0xNzEyMjcxMzQyMTNaMCMGCSqGSIb3DQEJBDEWBBRXJS7GC+sYrrb9YaLm
> nsFH3e/lyDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAQBTSz7X4URhT+u3b40YELnOT+lXirXP
> GGNb9UhQFZ+XAq8Fd9DTYs7A5EXpEDsByxnupctz48sG5Q8sosnZaMcQoIQvcPpg
> xgZ5Reo/qNlAbiWbGubt0wSCmwqJ1RbVlJu9zle8/7Y557YmQNMgEglnFus2Q8p4
> 9BuCK+e9bTuJ8JgLM6IokQdWcCWKevkWakHtBxrI/XrPPnPVqQbkS7/uKJ50FqqR
> Vv8Ip7dcGJCMaqKi+/VGoEuoDjt262MeKF1ZKI9Et0+wOEtnirMz97bByTyTHH6T
> 3ijPfaRyCNsdWXy3F8NHsI0I1Bo9mRRp7T4dlX04csVACIQvpmfbMLLL
> ```

Which when i base64 decode i get something like this:

> ```
> �ioz�"�}tzw(v)�!#��u���z{Ğ������Y첆�z{����!zf��il��h�졪z{ޖ�^������r�ig���i��0�
> ���M\��r�k���l�m����7��?�M5�sI�^����֧q����h�׭"w�E�)�{H��^���x�)^��i���隳������?�����ܡا��f�{8�5Xm�����^��1�[(j�+��(j�ޞ������ig�{4���ƥ�ig�#�
> org.xml.s�v��4�W�6WF���W�V7F���GW&��r'6S�6��FV�Mw is not allowed in prolog.�s����fƖB�FF���W'&�#���&WǓ� R� Rc @�0
> ```
>
> -w    e�0
>         *�H��
>       0<10  UUS10U
>       Ge�v�G'W7B���2�C `5P@10�&�E54�4�p�##s#mw02Z
>       161128133915Z0��1)0'U xt6QyeIFBMIcMJ5J�v�cGe���G��6�g

(And a lot more..)

However no matter what i try it seems like i cannot decrypt the response correctly, even when using their certificate for decryption.

They dont really have any documentation, however i have the java code from a program that works and can actually decode the responses correctly.

Here is the snippet from the java crypto client:

```
private String checkAndDecode(final String base64AndSigned, final Certificate signingCert) throws IOException, SignatureException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
final byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(base64AndSigned);

final PKCS7 p7 = new PKCS7(new DerInputStream(decoded));
final SignerInfo[] signerInfo = p7.verify();
final Certificate signerCertificate = signerInfo[0].getCertificate(p7);

if((signingCert != null) && !signingCert.equals(signerCertificate)) {
    throw new SignatureException("Signed by incorrect certificate");
}

return new String(p7.getContentInfo().getContentBytes());
}
```

Unfortunatly I dont really understand Java.

If anyone can help point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.
If you need more information please let me know and I will provide it.

Comment: So what is your problem, if it works?

Comment: You should have the key and certificate, then would this function be your solution? http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkcs7-decrypt.php

Comment: @Frank

Is that not used for decrypting emails?

Comment: I would expect `$response = $soapClient->function($xml);` to give you the response and any decryption to be handled by the `SoapClient` itself.